# MYSQL, slow performance group by with multiples tables with millions rows

Tags: mysql

I have three table with more than 1 millions of rows and one of my query take more than 30 seconds with a date range of 3 months. I have tried multiples index and I think I have respect index orders. I don't know what to do go get a better performance.

Here my query, create table statement, in my explain

```
SELECT
MAX(table2.id) as item_id,
MAX(table2.sampled_inspected) as sample_size,
table1.group_col AS ass_group_id


FROM

table1
INNER JOIN table2  ON table1.id = table2.assignment_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3  ON table1.po_id = table3.id
LEFT JOIN table4  ON table4.id = table3.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN table5  ON table5.id = table3.project_id

WHERE table1.recycled=0
    AND table2.inspection_status_id > 0
    AND table2.inspection_status_id != 50
    AND table3.importer_id = 215 AND table5.recycled = 0  AND table3.project_id IN ( '2062','2063','2064','2065' ) AND table2.inspection_completed_date >= DATE('2019-10-01')  AND table2.inspection_completed_date <= DATE('2020-01-29')
                        GROUP BY ass_group_id
```

and here my 5 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recycled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_col` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `po_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_assignment_po` (`po_id`),
  KEY `recycled` (`recycled`,`group_col`),
  KEY `group_col` (`group_col`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3324705 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assignment_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sampling_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_report` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `inspection_result_id` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inspection_completed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `recycled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qty_to_inspect` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `defect_rate` decimal(16,13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sampled_inspected` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `inspection_report_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `poline_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `production_line` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_wsxix_assignments` (`assignment_id`),
  KEY `index_inspection_report_reportid` (`inspection_report_id`),
  KEY `index_ai_inspection_completed_date` (`inspection_completed_date`),
  KEY `index_item_poline` (`poline_id`),
  KEY `index_item_poline_assignment` (`poline_id`,`assignment_id`),
  KEY `wsxix_assignments_items_inspection_status_id` (`inspection_status_id`),
  KEY `wsxix_assignments_items_inspection_result_id` (`inspection_result_id`),
  KEY `inspection_completed_date` (`inspection_completed_date`,`inspection_result_id`,`inspection_status_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3324705 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `table3` (
                          `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

                          `buyer_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `client_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `merchandiser_user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `factory_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `dc_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `supplier_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `importer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `project_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                          `tier_two_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          `store_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                          KEY `buyer_id` (`buyer_id`),
                          KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
                          KEY `merchandiser_user_id` (`merchandiser_user_id`),
                          KEY `FK_po_factory_companies_id` (`factory_id`),
                          KEY `FK_po_dc_companies_id` (`dc_id`),
                          KEY `index_po_parentid` (`parent_id`),
                          KEY `index_purchaseorders_cie` (`supplier_id`),
                          KEY `index_poimporter_cie` (`importer_id`),
                          KEY `index_purchaseorders_project` (`project_id`),
                          KEY `facory_importer_id` (`factory_id`,`importer_id`),
                          KEY `posu` (`project_id`,`supplier_id`),
                          KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
                          KEY `tier_two_id` (`tier_two_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34959 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table4` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_company_id` (`parent_company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=272 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table5` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recycled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `recycled` (`recycled`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2066 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these indexes:

```
table2:  (assignment_id, inspection_completed_date)
table2:  (inspection_completed_date, assignment_id)
table3:  (importer_id, project_id, supplier_id, id)
table3:  (project_id, importer_id, supplier_id, id)
table5:  (recycled, id)
table1:  (recycled, po_id, id, group_col)
```

Remove this; it adds nothing, but slows down the query:

```
    LEFT JOIN  table4  ON table4.id = table3.supplier_id
```